# Proceessing data in the groupBy clause

Tags: select, group-by, postgresql-9.1

My sql table is like:

```
SECTION ID; question_id;is_correct 

1;1;t

1;2;t

1;3;f 

1;4;f 

1;5;t

2;1;f

2;2;t

2;3;f

2;4;t

2;5;f
```

what i want is that for one section i get the result on the basis of the is_correct field.
The net result should be string such that if the is_correct =t then TRUE and if is_correct=f then FALSE get appended to the string.

So for the new result for the data given should be

```
SECTION_id;STRING

1;TRUE::TRUE::FALSE::FALSE::TRUE

2;FALSE::TRUE::FALSE::TRUE::FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for it with sql concatenate.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+concatenate